# perl dancer: passing database info to template

Tags: perl, templates, dancer

Following Dancer tutorial here:

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Tutorial.pod

I'm using my own sqlite3 database with this schema

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists location (location_code TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, stations INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE if not exists session (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT, sessions INTEGER, location_code TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(location_code) REFERENCES location(location_code));
```

My dancer code ( helloWorld.pm ) for the database:

```
package helloWorld;
use Dancer;
use DBI;
use File::Spec;
use File::Slurp;
use Template;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

set 'template' => 'template_toolkit';
set 'logger'   => 'console';

my $base_dir = qq(/home/automation/scripts/Area51/perl/dancer);

# database crap
sub connect_db {
 my $db = qw(/home/automation/scripts/Area51/perl/dancer/sessions.sqlite);
 my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$db", "", "",
   { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 });
 return $dbh;
}

    sub init_db {
 my $db = connect_db();
 my $file = qq($base_dir/schema.sql);
 my $schema = read_file($file);
 $db->do($schema) or die $db->errstr;
    }

get '/' => sub {
 my $branch_code = qq(BPT);
 my $dbh = connect_db();
 my $sql = q(SELECT * FROM session);
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die $dbh->errstr;
 $sth->execute or die $dbh->errstr;
 my $key_field = q(id);
 template 'show_entries.tt', {
  'branch' => $branch_code,
  'data' => $sth->fetchall_hashref($key_field),
 };
};

init_db();
true;
```

Tried the example template on the site, doesn't work.

```
<% FOREACH id IN data.keys.nsort %>
  <li>Date is: <% data.$id.sessions %> </li>
<% END %>
```

Produces page but with no data. How do I troubleshoot this as no clues
come up in the console/cli?

*** UPDATE ***
If I change the database code to this:

```
get '/' => sub {
    my $branch_code = qq(BPT);
    my $dbh = connect_db();
    my $sql = 'SELECT * FROM session';
    #my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die $dbh->errstr;
    #$sth->execute or die $dbh->errstr;
    #my $key_field = q(id);
    my $entries = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sql,{});
    template 'show_entries.tt', {


'branch' => $branch_code,
        #'data' => $sth->fetchall_hashref('id'),
        'data' => @$entries,
    };
};
```

I get one result from the table in the template. So the info is being passed, but the
syntax for the template does not work as described. This does fit with Template Toolkit syntax.

Thanks

Bubnoff

EDIT/RESOLUTION **

David reminded me of Data::Dumper which confirmed that the problem was indeed with the Template configuration. I commented out the template directive in the config file thinking that it would be redundant since it was in the code itself. WRONG!!! It must be configured in the YAML. Deleting an octothorpe in the config set everything to rights. Now I'm just embarrassed about not trying Data::Dumper in the first place. Thanks David!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, make sure you're passing what you think you're passing to the template.

Assign the result of $sth->fetchall_hashref($key_field) to a temporary scalar, then dump it with Data::Dump or Data::Dumper (or see [Dancer::Plugin::DebugDump](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dancer-Plugin-DebugDump) for a way to make it dead easy).

Comment: Data::Dumper shows that the expected data is being passed as a hash. As expected. I'm thinking something is wrong with my template configuration. Maybe it's trying to use template simple instead of template toolkit. It's configured directly in the code though.

Comment: I'm thinking about bypassing the framework rather than try to decipher the template idiosyncrasies. I can serialize it as JSON and do an ajax call rather than fight the framework.

Comment: Thanks for your help David -- It was the template config. Even though it was configured at the top of the code it had to be setup in the YAML config as well. Strange how simple solutions bring bliss from hate. Confirming the data passed narrowed down the problem to the template and the eventual culprit.

Comment: You're welcome, and glad to see you got it sorted.  I will try to reproduce the problem you saw where using `setting` to select the template engine at runtime rather than in the config file didn't work, as it should work!  It did indeed work as expected for me with a very basic test case: https://gist.github.com/796692

Comment: Ahah - that test case works, but if I add a config.yml file, even just containg `appname: Test`, it stops working.  You've found a bug in Dancer which I've just opened an issue for, and which should be fixed soon - thank you for finding it!  Opened issue at https://github.com/sukria/Dancer/issues/issue/265

Comment: You're welcome. Dancer is a great project. Glad to see it being resolved.